# MongoDB configuration with custom resource definition

Tags: mongodb

I am using Custom Resource Definition from MongoDB community to deploy a MongoDB ReplicaSet in one K8s cluster. I am facing a problem between the members of the replica. They all have the same priority (1 as default) and this can not be changed. Every time I am changing it manually through mongosh commands, the cluster-config is "locked" and applied which ends up without any changes.

***Is it a way to configure the priority of the members when the MongoDB instance is deployed and initialised?***

*Any help highly appreciated*

My Mongodb config:

```
---
apiVersion: mongodbcommunity.mongodb.com/v1
kind: MongoDBCommunity
metadata:
  name: mongodb
  namespace: mongodb
spec:
  members: 2
  type: ReplicaSet
  version: "6.0.4"
  arbiters: 1
  security:
    authentication:
      modes:
      - SCRAM
  users:
  - name: root
    db: admin
    passwordSecretRef:
      name: root-user-password
    roles:
    - name: clusterAdmin
      db: admin
    - name: userAdminAnyDatabase
      db: admin
    scramCredentialsSecretName: connect-scram-1
  - name: admin
    db: admin
    passwordSecretRef:
      name: admin-user-password
    roles:
    - name: root
      db: admin
    scramCredentialsSecretName: connect-scram-2
  additionalMongodConfig:
    storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.journalCompressor: zlib
  statefulSet:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: mongod
            resources:
              limits:
                cpu: "1"
                memory: 4Gi
              requests:
                cpu: 500m
                memory: 2Gi
          - name: mongodb-agent
            resources:
              limits:
                cpu: "0.5"
                memory: 500M
              requests:
                cpu: "0.2"
                memory: 250M      
          affinity:
            podAntiAffinity:
              preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
                - weight: 100
                  podAffinityTerm:
                    labelSelector:
                      matchExpressions:
                        - key: app
                          operator: In
                          values:
                            - mongodb
                    topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
            nodeAffinity:
              requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
                nodeSelectorTerms:
                - matchExpressions:
                  - key: app
                    operator: In
                    values:
                    - mongodb
      volumeClaimTemplates:
      - metadata:
          name: data-volume
        spec:
          accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
          resources:
            requests:
              storage: 10G
      - metadata:
          name: logs-volume
        spec:
          accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
          resources:
            requests:
              storage: 10G
```

Comment: I have no clue about Kubernetes, does `members: 2` mean 2 nodes? And is `arbiters: 1` plus one arbiter, i.e. three instances in total?

Comment: 2 members I mean two primary members and 1 arbiter. So the Replica Set has three members.